# Find the probability of two of nine independent events occurring.

Tags: probability, independence

I need the probability of any *two* independent events occurring out of a list of nine for a formula I'm creating (exactly two). I'm not even sure where to start as probability is not my strong suit.

Their probabilities are: $.250$, $.260$, $.270$, $.280$, $.290$, $.300$, $.310$, $.315$, $.329$

*This is for an independent study, not an assignment

Comment: Exactly two, at least two, or for any given specific pair?

Comment: Exactly two occurring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly two means that two events occur and the other seven don't. For instance that probability that the first two occur and the other seven don't is $$ p_1p_2(1-p_3)(1-p_4)\ldots(1-p_9)$$ where $p_1=.250,$ $p_2 = .260,$ etc. To get the probability that exactly two occur, you need to compute this for each possible pair and then add them all up. (Note there are thirty six possible pairs.)

It might be instructive to try this for a smaller problem first (say, three rather than nine events) to make sure you understand.